# Does Jetty support HTTP Chunked Responses/Transfer-Encoding?

Tags: jetty, embedded-jetty

I'm currently using Jetty 8 and I'd like to write several events (text) in a servlet response. For example:

write start
write event2
write event3
write complete

All delimited by \n

The span of this response would probably be no more than 20 seconds, but the client should receive each event (line) as it happens. I could not find any documentation on this but I wanted to check with the community.

If Jetty doesn't this, are there any other servlet engines that do and can also be embedded?

BTW, I tried the following but no data is received until the servlet returns and then it's received all at once.

```
  resp.setContentType("text/html");
    resp.setHeader("Transfer-Encoding", "chunked");
    resp.getWriter().write("closing");
    resp.getWriter().flush();

    try {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    resp.getWriter().write("closed");
    resp.getWriter().flush();
```

**Edit: must use \r\n for line terminator**

Answer (score 2):

It works if each line is terminated by \r\n

```
    resp.setContentType("text/html");
    resp.setHeader("Transfer-Encoding", "chunked");
    resp.getWriter().write("closing\r\n");
    resp.getWriter().flush();

    try {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    resp.getWriter().write("closed\r\n");
    resp.getWriter().flush();
```